# mail-client issue in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

My script should take the user inputs and login to the server but when I give it the inputs it false and I tried different servers and different emails and the passwords are correct. How can I determine what's wrong?

```
import smtplib

sent = 'true'
ss = 'true'
repeat = 1



while sent == 'true':

m_email = input ('Enter Your Email Address: ')
m_server = input ('Entere Your Email Server: ')
m_auth = input ('username?\n')
p_auth = input  ('password?\n')

r_email = input ('enter the reciver email: ')

subject =  input ('enter Your Subject: ')
subject = 'subject '+ subject
m_massege = input ('Your Massege: ')

massege = subject  + '\n \n'  + m_massege

while ss == 'true' or repeat == "5" :

    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP(m_server)
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.login(m_auth,p_auth)
        server.Sendmail(m_email,r_mail,massege)

        print ("Mail Sent Successfully!")
        sent = 'false'
    except:
        print ('sending failed')
        repeat =+ 1
        exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I've also had issues with smtplib and what I found was that it was not actually a code issue but rather an issue with the email account. For example, in my case I was trying to log into my yahoo mail account to automate emails and it kept failing so I had to go to my yahoo account security settings and enable "allow unsecured application login".

Point is: the problem isn't with your code but with the security settings on the email accounts (For me neither gmail nor yahoo worked).